# Opening a class by typing its name in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm working on a large project with a lot of packages and classes. Its a pain to have to find the right package and then the right file to open. Is there a way to just type in the name of the class that I want to open, and have intellij offer autocomplete suggestions while I type, and then open that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control-N and start typing the class name works for me.

Control-Shift-N does the same trick, but for file names.

Selecting in the source window will open the class in the left explorer pane.  Much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Ctrl+N - of course this answer is too short to post by itself.

Comment: You can also use Ctrl+Shift+N to find files in a similar manner.

Answer (score 2):

cmd + N for java classes. 
cmd + shift + N for files.
Double tap on shift for both if you have intellij 13

Comment: It's actually "double shift" not triple, unless that's a Mac difference.